# I have problems getting a response with retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I have problems getting a response with retrofit. 
My response is not successful and I don't know why.
I will post here my json array, my main activity named `Education_Classes`, 
and I will post my classes too.

```
{
  "classes": [
    {
      "class_id": "1",
      "class_name": "class1",
      "class_description": "des1"
    },
    {
      "class_id": "2",
      "class_name": "class2",
      "class_description": "des2"
    },
    {
      "class_id": "3",
      "class_name": "class3",
      "class_description": "des3"
    }
  ],
  "status": "1"
}
```

**Main classess**:

```
public class Education_Classes extends AppCompatActivity {


    private List < Classes > classesList = new ArrayList <>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ClassesAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_education__classes );

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById( R.id.recyclerClasses );

        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl( "http://bimehsan.ir/api-v1/" ).addConverterFactory( GsonConverterFactory.create() );
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        final WebService webService = retrofit.create( WebService.class );


        SharedPreferences shareToken = getSharedPreferences( "userdetails", MODE_PRIVATE );


        String getToken = shareToken.getString( "token", "no name" );

        String tokeyWhittokenType = "Bearer" + " " + getToken;


        Call < ClassesResponse > call = webService.getClasses( tokeyWhittokenType );

        call.enqueue( new Callback < ClassesResponse >() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call < ClassesResponse > call, Response < ClassesResponse > response) {


                if ( response.isSuccessful() ) {

                    Toast.makeText( Education_Classes.this, "Sucsess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                    classesList = response.body().getClasses();
                    mAdapter = new ClassesAdapter( classesList );
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( getApplicationContext() );
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager( mLayoutManager );
                    recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator() );
                    recyclerView.setAdapter( mAdapter );

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText( Education_Classes.this, "خطا در گرفتن اطلاعات", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call < ClassesResponse > call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText( Education_Classes.this, "اتصال خود را به اینتریت بررسی نمایید.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            }


        } );

    }
}
```

**ClassesResponse**:

```
public class ClassesResponse {

    private List<Classes> classes;
    private String status;


    public ClassesResponse(List<Classes> classes, String status) {
        this.classes = classes;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Classes> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

    public void setClasses(List<Classes> classes) {
        this.classes = classes;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}


public class Classes {

    private String class_id;
    private String class_name;
    private String class_description;


    public Classes(String class_id, String class_name, String class_description) {
        this.class_id = class_id;
        this.class_name = class_name;
        this.class_description = class_description;
    }

    public String getClass_id() {
        return class_id;
    }

    public void setClass_id(String class_id) {
        this.class_id = class_id;
    }

    public String getClass_name() {
        return class_name;
    }

    public void setClass_name(String class_name) {
        this.class_name = class_name;
    }

    public String getClass_description() {
        return class_description;
    }

    public void setClass_description(String class_description) {
        this.class_description = class_description;
    }
}
```

And my **webService**:

```
public interface WebService {

    @POST("login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<User> login(@Field("national_code") String national_code, @Field("password") String password);


    @GET("all-classes")
    Call<ClassesResponse> getClasses(@Header("Authorization") String tokeyWhittokenType);

}
```

I expect my `response.isSuccessful()` should be true, but it is false!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194375/discussion-on-question-by-hengameh-ghasemi-i-have-problems-getting-a-response-wi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is calling Api

Api of allClasses is **POST** Request but you send **GET** Request:

change the:

```
@GET("all-classes")
```

to:

```
@POST("all-classes")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I find my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `@SerializedName("response_key")` annotation to the variables of your response:

```
public class ClassesResponse {

    @SerializedName("classes")
    private List<Classes> classes;
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;


    public ClassesResponse(List<Classes> classes, String status) {
        this.classes = classes;
        this.status = status;
    }

    public List<Classes> getClasses() {
        return classes;
    }

    public void setClasses(List<Classes> classes) {
        this.classes = classes;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}


public class Classes {

    @SerializedName("class_id")
    private String class_id;
    @SerializedName("class_name")
    private String class_name;
    @SerializedName("class_description")
    private String class_description;


    public Classes(String class_id, String class_name, String class_description) {
        this.class_id = class_id;
        this.class_name = class_name;
        this.class_description = class_description;
    }

    public String getClass_id() {
        return class_id;
    }

    public void setClass_id(String class_id) {
        this.class_id = class_id;
    }

    public String getClass_name() {
        return class_name;
    }

    public void setClass_name(String class_name) {
        this.class_name = class_name;
    }

    public String getClass_description() {
        return class_description;
    }

    public void setClass_description(String class_description) {
        this.class_description = class_description;
    }
}
```

Plus i did test it on the `Postman`. That's a POST request not a GET so you need to change your `@GET("all-classes")` to `@POST("all_classes")`

Comment: i changed my tow class to :    
   @SerializedName("class_id")
    private String class_id;
    @SerializedName("class_name")
    private String class_name;
    @SerializedName("class_description")
    private String class_description;  and also to ........  @SerializedName("classes")
    private List<Classes> classes;
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;    but it did not  word

Comment: @StavroXHarda my url is  http://bimehsan.ir/api-v1/all-classes and you cat put what ever you whant in Authorization in header and you can test it by yourself and you can see it is working well

Comment: Looks like your `@GET("all-classes")` needs to change to `@Post("all-classes")`

Comment: Thank a lot Stavro you are right and I found my mistake

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The request was returning a null object. But the android code was right. Problem was in the server code. check the server code. May be this will help